# Comparing values in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

How to compare objects in 2 distinct lists?
I have two list List#1 and List#2 in each there could be 1 or  more objects i need to transport all changes from #1 to #2. So they would be the same nevertheless the changes from #2. It should work only from #1 -> #2. List(s) may not be ordered and could contain different values for object therefore I can´t order by id. I need to find which object from #1 is comparable to object from #2 and then copy only changes from #1 to #2.

Comment: I presume all objects in those lists are the same class. In such case you just need to override equals() method of this class to provide your custom comparison behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I think you are trying to do from your question (with No code). You are trying to **populate List #2 with content of List #1 and you dont want duplicate data.**

You can do one thing if you want to add content of List 1 and List 2 in one list. Use a **HashSet**. HashSet doesn't allow duplication of Data. So, once your List1 is updated in HashSet, iterate through List2 and populate the HashSet with content of List2.

**Result**- You will get a hashSet of Unique data from both List1 and List2

You can use this Tutorial - http://www.javatpoint.com/HashSet-class-in-collection-framework

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all ideas. As it turns out collection was good hint which way to go. I actually used HashMap. I could construct keys and based on key i can compare and if neccessary  add or delete entry.